# multiple values not getting inserted on submit button in php

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    $sql_select="select *  from  tb_weight_slot ";
    query_select=mysql_query($sql_select);
    while($row_select=mysql_fetch_array($query_select))
    {
?>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="weight[]" value="<?php echo $row_select["weight_slot_name"]; ?>" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" style="width:100px; height:22px; float:left; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;"  /></td>
    </tr>

<?php 
    }
?>
    </table>

    <br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" />
```

in this code i am fetching weight slots from a table and displaying them in a page....i have dynamically added a row named rate[].....now what i want is that when i enter rate  for multiple fields as there is a while loop and click on submit button then the weight slot and rate should get inserted in a new table .... but it is not getting inserted.....my submit code is ....

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["save"]))
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["weight"]); $i++)
    {
        $rate=$_POST["rate"][$i];
        mysql_query("insert into tb_weight_rate_management (rate) values (".$rate.")");  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: first: you put submit button into the loop, it is wrong! Second: Where is your tag <form>?

Comment: the loop thing i have corrected but form is in the right place

Comment: you want insert every weight and rate as couple?

Answer (score 0):

The array `$_POST["weight"]` is totally independent from the array `$_POST["rate"]`. You are generating an index from the array length of `$_POST["weight"]` and iterating with this over `$_POST["rate"]`.

You are not checking whether `$_POST["rate"][$i]` actually is set. As the value is not quoted in the SQL, that might cause an error.

Better:

```
 <?php

          for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["rate"]); $i++)
          {
              $rate=$_POST["rate"][$i];
              if ( !empty($rate) )
                  mysql_query("insert into tb_weight_rate_management (rate) values ('".$rate."')");  
          }


    ?>
```